# Translation for German "brav aussehen"

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

Although related to English *brave*, the German word *brav* doesn't mean being courageous (any more). It rather has the sense of decency. "Sei brav", for instance, would be translated as "Be a good boy/girl".

I often struggle with a translation for this word. Now I'm trying to find a good translation for "brav aussehen". There's possibly not a single word as it depends on context what *brav* really conveys, but I'm wondering if there is a word, though.

Example 1:

> Im Schlaf sieht er/sie so brav aus.
>   While asleep he/she looks so __.

This could be said about a child. It kinda implies that it's a naughty child, but while sleeping he/she appears like being a good boy/girl.

Example 2:

> Sie mag nicht mehr so brav aussehen.
>   She doesn't want to look so __ any more.

This could be said about a woman that usually wears plain clothes and doesn't attract men, and who likes to change that.

The opposite, I guess, is in both cases *naughty*. But is there a word that would fit in both sentences above?

I tried finding German synonyms (*lieb*, *anständig*) and translating those. The results are "good", "nice", "sweet", "well-behaved", "decent", "proper". It seems to me that none of these words is a good translation.

For instance, while "good", generally speaking, is a good translation for *brav* (cf. good boy/girl), I guess it would differently be understood in both sentences above — good-looking or cute, that is.

Other words, like "well-behaved", do only fit in one context. Dictionaries (Oxford, M-W) define that as "behaving in a polite and correct way" and to my mind dressing in plain clothes is neither polite nor correct. And the Urban dictionary doesn't have a definition for well-behaved, so I don't think that any slang definition would apply here.

For the same reasons I dismiss the other words, too.

So, is there a word that would match both contexts? As a matter of course, the sentences do not need to be a verbatim translation; it's fine to rephrase them.

---

Addendum: In German it's possible to say "brav wirken" in both sentences. *Wirken* means *to appear*, *to seem*. I tried to get to a solution by thinking about this alternative.

The translations then would be

> While asleep she appears to be __.
>   She doesn't want to give the impression of being __ any more.

I feel like the only way to finish the first sentence is "to be a good boy/girl" and I tend to believe that the version with "to look" also requires that and, hence, I'm coming to the conclusion that there's no adjective that would fit the role.

Comment: The word is *well-behaved*. As indeed LEO will suggest.

Comment: @RegDwigнt That could be an accurate translation, but how often in English would we say of a sleeping child *he/she looks so well-behaved*? And *well-behaved* is somewhat archaic. It seems to belong to an era when children were best seen and not heard. I think the usual expression these days would be *he/she looks so angelic*.

Comment: Is no one going to suggest *innocent*?

Comment: @RegDwigнt If well-behaved *is* the word to go with, this would be an answer (contradicting my statement above that this word wouldn't fit) as opposed to be a reason for closing as off-topic. Dictionaries do not suggest that well-behaved would work in the second example. The definition (Oxford, M-W) is "behaving in a polite or correct way". Dressing in plain clothes is neither polite nor correct.

Comment: Sounds like [*"butter wouldn't melt in her mouth"*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/butter-wouldn-t-melt-in-sb-s-mouth).

Comment: I get the sense that "brav" is being used for a number of shades of the same general attribute of being "pure" or "chaste".  You also may have more luck Googling synonyms for "pure" and "chaste".

Comment: @Em1: "give the impression of *being*" asks for a noun phrase, e.g. one that refers to a stereotype ("a spinster", "a librarian", or "no fun") whereas "look so" asks for an adjective that refers to outward appearance, and could take an adjective like "frumpy" or "plain" or "spinsterish" or "well-behaved" or "prim and proper".

Comment: @TimRomano I don't think that it requires a noun phrase. OALD has an example with an adjective: "She gives the impression of being very busy."

Comment: @WS2: I do not understand. "It's an accurate translation, *but*"? How is that a but? The original is just as seldom, and just as archaic. This is not "an accurate translation, but". This is the accurate translation, period. And it's in the most popular German-English dictionary. The top entry, too. I am really at a loss at what's going on here. "Like an angel" is a horrible translation. "Like a plain Jane" is pathetic. Is any of the upvoters a native speaker of German? Does anyone here speak German at all, except for the OP?

Comment: @Em1 dressing in plain clothes is neither polite nor correct in German, either. Except when you are looking at a phrase that says just that. Then you have to translate the phrase as saying just that. If the original says "She doesn't want to give the impression of being well-behaved", then your English translation must say "She doesn't want to give the impression of being well-behaved", too. Your job as a translator is not to correct; it is but to translate.

Comment: And yes, all that said, *brav* very much is a difficult word to translate. But then again, so is *Mutter* or *Hose*. Or any word, for that matter. You have to translate every single occurrence of every single word individually. By presenting two completely different examples side by side, you're already going against that basic rule.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Yes, the word "brav" has so many nuances that it is sheer impossible to find a single word that fits all cases. And yes, these two examples I gave are quite at the opposite end of the entire nuance range. On the other hand, I think that when you take the plain definition of "brav", you can always arrive at the specific connotation in each context. I'm kinda looking for an English word, if any exists, that would fit the role here.

Comment: As a non-native English speaker, I didn't regard the word "well-behaved" as such. If I'm mistaken on that, fair enough; but again this is an answer then. So, please go ahead and post it as an answer.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I think more clarification is called for on what exactly is meant by *translate*. It is more art than science. Something that may have been considered an accurate rendering fifty years ago, with changes in usage etc. may be well adrift today. When did you last hear a teacher or any professional describe a child as *well behaved*. It is an outmoded and insufficient concept, and is replaced with a plethora of descriptors.

Comment: @EM1: I don't mean that it requires a noun-phrase grammatically, but that in the way you want to use it,  a noun phrase would be more a likely choice there.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't come up with a single word (I don't think there is one), but I've come up with a construction that I think might work.

You said that *wirken* means *to appear, to seem*. One solution would be to use *like*.

Example 1:

> While asleep he/she looks **like an angel**.

Example 2:

> She doesn't want to look **like a plain Jane**.

What you put after *like* would obviously depend on what you’re trying to say and there isn't a single word that would cover all situations. But I think it’s a construction that would usually work well when needing to translate *brav wirken* as you've described it.

Comment: +1 I agree with "angel" for a child who seems good when they're sleeping, but may be a terror when awake. And I agree that this doesn't work for the plainly clothed woman.

Comment: +1 for "looks like an angel". But I'm not sure that *plain Jane* is the best translation (not that I can think of anything better).

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, OP is looking for a single word in English to use for the German word "brav".  "Angel" and "plain Jane" are not interchangeable in the OP's sample sentences.

Comment: @Kristina Lopez - that's why my first sentence reads *I haven't come up with a single word, but..."*. I don't think you're going to find a synonym in English. Also, we can't possibly know all the situations in which *brav* would be appropriate in German. I think the construciton *like* followed by something (probably a figure of speech) would work. You'd just have to figure out that figure for a given situation, perhaps by asking on this forum.

Answer (score 0):

I think that ***"chaste"*** works for both examples based on two of the definitions on [MWO](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chaste):

> : morally pure or decent : not sinful
>
> : simple or plain

Comment: I feel like "chaste" is a bit over the top. It suggests too much "not having sex" or "not expressing sexual feelings". A good translation back into German regardless of context would be "keusch" and that's certainly not what I'd like to express. "Eine brave Frau" may express sexual feelings but probably in a very, erm, shy way. (Not the best word but hard to explain in a few words.)

Comment: That said, the word "brav" may indeed have the connotation of being virginal when applied to a woman, so it's certainly not that far off. But I can hardly see how this word could be applied to a child. Or does the word maybe cover a wider range as the German counterpart, i.e. is not too strongly related to "not having sex"?

Comment: While not the first word in my list to describe well-behaved children, "chaste" in the sense of "morally pure or decent: not sinful" could apply to a child who's otherwise naughty behavior could be considered "full of the devil" or "sinful".

Comment: I hate to be negative but there is no way to use chaste outside of a sexual connotation.  Morally pure or decent in the sense of abstaining from sex outside of marriage.

Comment: @michael_timofeev, there is a way to use chaste outside of a sexual connotation - clearly, given the additional definitions - but *without*  context, it normally would be associated with abstinence from sex.  *With* context, it is a viable option that fits both of OP's sample sentences.

Comment: @KristinaLopez do you speak German?  Because if you do, then we can have a discussion about whether brav can be translated to chaste in English.

Comment: @KristinaLopez chaste translated into German (keusch) is all about sexuality...as an example, my German dictionary gives "chaste like a nun."  Means the same in English as it does in German: free of sexual needs, wants, or desires.

Comment: @michael_timofeev, I do speak some German, not to the extent of being a translator but that's not what is at issue here and this *is*  an English Language Usage site after all. :-)  The point of the OP's question is not to find the English equivalent of "keusch" but a suitable English word to fit both the sample sentences and stand in for "brav".  Is "keusch" synonymous with "brav" in German?  Could be...but that's not the particular definition I'm suggesting by offering "chaste".  Did you see the other definitions?

Comment: @KristinaLopez yes, I did.  You ignored the main definitions in your quote of Merriam Webster, which is innocent of sexual intercourse, or celibate or pure in thought.  How can that apply to a little boy sleeping? Unless chaste has since been bowlderized.  On another note, I do like your comment above about angel.

Comment: @KristinaLopez keusch and brav could be synonymous in German depending on context...see my example...but cannot be so in English...so a boy that looks brav you cannot say he looks chaste.

Comment: @michael_timofeev, yes, I omitted the first definition because *that* particular one did not apply.  I'm not clear on why you have an aversion to using "chaste" for any other than that first definition.  Feel free to downvote my answer but I am standing by it as a possible substitution for "brav", as the OP described.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote it.  Let's wait and see what other people say, but unless they speak German it's all guessing.

Comment: @michael_timofeev Are you a bilingual speaker of English and German? — I acknowledge that it is hard to answer the question if you're not good at both. In the first place I thought I'd ask on German.SE, as those understand the German word with all it nuances perfectly. But then I realized that you need good understanding of the English language, so I chose this way.

Comment: So, my point is now that definition clearly suggests "chaste equals keusch", on the other hand not all possible nuances are listed in a dictionary (otherwise I could answer my question myself). I don't know any German dictionary whose definition of "brav" is complete enough for language learners to fully comprehend its meaning. So, only a native English speaker may tell whether or not "chaste" may be applied in that context.

Comment: @KristinaLopez Just to clarify, although michael_timofeev already said it: "brav" and "keusch", in general, are not synonyms. But they have a tiny overlap in meaning. A person that doesn't have sex at all, would be "keusch". A priest is (at least has to be) "keusch". This meaning is not covered by "brav". Not at all. However, as implied in my example, a person that is considered (too) "brav", might be virginal or people believe that that is the case. But I can't think of any sentence where the words could be interchanged. — And I think that "chaste" is the counterpart to "keusch".

Comment: @Em1, here in the US, chaste would be also used to describe nuns and (some) priests who live a life of sexual abstinence but to relegate the word "chaste" to just that one meaning would be doing it and all words an injustice. That being said, by your need to apply a single English word to two not-exactly-the-same meanings has greatly limited the answers to your question.  Perhaps it is best said that your two examples would need distinctly different words to best fill ***that*** specific use of "brav".

Answer (score 0):

Translation isn't so much taking each word and converting it to an equivalent as it is finding a similar way of looking at the world and expressing that. This is the problem you're running into when asking for a single word. For example, how do you translate *Schadenfreude* into English? You can't. You need to explain what the word means. This is similar to trying to explain idioms with a single word.

*Brav* has many meanings and uses. For example,

> Was für ein braver Hund.

means

> What a good / obedient / loyal / faithful dog.

*Brav* has all of those meanings at that same time. Which one is "best"? Depends on the context.

> "Jetzt guck doch mal hin, er sieht so brav aus, wenn er seine Hausaufgaben macht."

In this case, *brav* means well-behaved, obedient, good, dutiful. All of the things that you can associate with a boy doing his homework.

The common thread is *well-behaved*, but that might not be the speaker's meaning when talking about the dog or the little boy.

When trying to translate

> Sie mag nicht mehr so brav aussehen

what is the context? Are you trying to say she doesn't want to be a goody two shoes (the opposite of *Tussi* in German?). As in

> Ich will nicht mehr wie eine Tussi aussehen. Ich will, dass die Leute mich brav ansehen.
>   (I don't want people to think I'm a bad girl anymore, I want them to think I'm a "good" girl.)

*Brav* could be used sarcastically

> Du siehst so brav aus mit deinem Minirock.

or

> Naja, du siehst ja ganz brav aus mit diesem Outfit.
>   (You look really chaste / pure / innocent with that outfit.)

Of course, the English translation lacks the sarcasm that this has in German.

In a nutshell, you need to give more context, so we can find the right expression because *brav* means many things. That's why people are struggling to find the right word. "He looks like an angel" is apt, but you can say that in German ("Er sieht aus wie ein Engel.") and it doesn't quite mean *brav*.

On another note, I encourage you to read Umbeto Eco's book Mouse or Rat? which addresses this subject. (The problems of translation and how some things are a frustrating compromise.)

Comment: You might consider making this a comment since it is asking for more clarification from the OP.

Comment: Yes, you cannot find a pair of words that is always the right translation. And I'm not really looking for a word that always is the translation for "brav". But there are words that fit in 99%. "Green/Grün" for example. Not only the color, but also in respect to politics, fruits, lack of experience, covered with grass. I was just wondering if there's a word in English that kinda fits the role here for "brav". That's why I gave two examples with quite a different connotation, just to cover the whole range with just two examples. Anyway.

Comment: @Em1 I think it best if you stop thinking of translation as "what does this word mean in English / German?" And start thinking about the meaning a sentence has and trying to convert that.  You will find that some words do have one to one translations.  Brav kind of does but kind of doesn't.  Just to give you another example, Chinese has an expression that is used to give people / groups encouragement for difficult things or activitites (加油) which literally means to oil something, but if you try and translate it directly into English in a sentence it doesn't work.

Comment: @Em1 if you want to translate those two sentences use "well behaved" or "good" but as WS2 points out "how often in English would we say of a sleeping child...."  Also "good" doesn't say much in English so an English speaker will ask "what do you mean by she doesn't want to be good anymore?"